# How to use the output parameter in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use the @ResultGroup as a output parameter in C#.

Please help me do this.

This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [DBAzmoon]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[SearchInGroup]
@GroupName nvarchar(50),
@ResultGroup int output
AS
if(Exists(select* From TblGroup where GroupName=@GroupName))
    set @ResultGroup=1
else
Begin
  set @ResultGroup=0
    Insert Into TblGroup(GroupName) Values (@GroupName)
End
```

Comment: if you are wanting to get the `@ResultGroup` variable returned you need to do a Select on the `@ResultGroup` variable so that you get it's returned value from the query. you can look at some `SQL Tutorials` here is 1 to start with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: also you are not using any Linq code here so your question is rather confusing in regards to what you have show vs what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
int ResultGroup;    
context.SearchInGroup(GroupName ,ref ResultGroup)
```

Try to follow this post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures